# How to open programs found in Software Center?

Tags: installed-programs

I am trying to locate the Software Updater which disappeared from my left panel of programs. I managed to locate it in the Software Center but clicking on it doesn't open it or help me locate it - it just shows me it exists.

The same happens with Glipper, the clipboard utility. I can find them both (the Software Updater and Glipper), when I do a search in the Software Center, but neither lets me click on them in order to open them, nor can I locate either of the above programs in ClassicMenu Indicator.

Where are they? How do I actually open the programs which Ubuntu tells me are installed? Itm ay seem like a stupid question but I am new to Linux and many things seem counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: Open the Dash (~Start Menu) and search for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things you can do:

1. Open Dash by either accessing it with a mouse click at the top left of your screen or by simply pressing the 'Windows' key on your keyboard. Then type in 'Software & Updates', this will open it up for you...
2. Now right click on the icon at the left of your screen that represents 'Software & Updates' and select 'Lock to Launcher', this will keep the icon on the Launcher for easy, future access

Screenshot here to demonstrate the 'lock' process:

[image]

Comment: And that, Andrew.46 was how to answer a question. Thank you!! ))